# Future callouts when trigger fires from batch job

Tags: apex, batch, future

I have a batch job that goes through a list of a custom objects and updates certain field. This is working correctly.

The custom object is part of a managed packaged. On the custom object is a trigger that runs after it is updated. This trigger code then calls an `@future (callout=true)` method that calls an external API, updating a sale value in an external system.

When the custom object is updated via the UI or DML in the developer console, the sale value in the external system is updated, so the trigger and subsequent callout are firing. However when done as part of a batch job, the custom objects are being updated but the sale values in external systems aren't being, so it looks like this callout isn't being made. Is there any way to confirm this?
I've read that you can't call a future method from inside a batch job. Is this the issue?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to call a future from a batch: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AqdVIAS. Oddly enough, the official documentation on future methods (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) does not mention that. In any case, check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76893/debug-or-view-status-of-a-future-method to see how to check whether your future method has ran or not.

Comment: The doc here states that future can't be called from batch - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm . The Dan Appleman pattern on asynchronous apex gets around this issue - no need for future - see http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/design-patternsasynchronousapex.